# Laravel limit result of multiple record table select based on if all records meet specific criteria

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table that has multiple records with the same foreign key (work_order_id).  Those records have a status field (Pending or Completed).  I only want to return those work_order_id's where all the records for that work_order_id match status = Completed.  If there are 5 records with work_order_id 95000 and 1 of them has a status of Pending and the rest are status = Completed I do not want to return work_order_id 95000 in the result.

I am currently using a foreach loop in PHP that is not efficient at all.  As the record count grows I am running into the query timeout.

```
 $work_orders = DB::table('work_orders')
            ->select(
                'work_orders.*',
                'vehicles.vin',
                'work_orders.transportation_type as transport',
                'clients.name as client_name',
                'events.event_name as event_name'
            )
            ->where('status', '!=', 'Closed')
            ->leftJoin('vehicles', 'vehicles.id', '=', 'work_orders.gsm_vehicle_id')
            ->leftJoin('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'work_orders.client_id')
            ->leftJoin('events', 'events.id', '=', 'work_orders.gsm_event_id')
            ->get();


        foreach ($work_orders as $wo) {
            $tasks = DB::table("work_order_tasks")
                ->where("work_order_id", $wo->id)
                ->where("status", "<>", "Completed")
                ->count();
            if ($tasks == 0) {
                $results[] = $wo;
            }
        }
```

I ended up coming up with a solution.  I used two queries.  First one gets the list of work_order_id's.  I pass that into a where in on the second query to get my result.

```
$completedWO = DB::select(
            DB::raw("
            SELECT DISTINCT
                r.work_order_id
            FROM
                work_order_tasks AS r
            WHERE
                NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT
                    work_order_id
                FROM
                    work_order_tasks
                WHERE
                work_order_id = r.work_order_id
                AND STATUS = 'Pending')
                ORDER BY r.work_order_id ASC
            "));

            $output = array_map(function ($object) { return $object->work_order_id; }, $completedWO);
            $wo = "'" . implode("', '", $output) . "'";
           
        $results = DB::table('work_orders')
            ->select(
                'work_orders.*',
                'vehicles.vin',
                'work_orders.transportation_type as transport',
                'clients.name as client_name',
                'events.event_name as event_name'
            )
            ->leftJoin('vehicles', 'vehicles.id', '=', 'work_orders.gsm_vehicle_id')
            ->leftJoin('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'work_orders.client_id')
            ->leftJoin('events', 'events.id', '=', 'work_orders.gsm_event_id')
            ->where('work_orders.status', '!=', 'Closed')
            ->whereRaw('work_orders.id IN ('. $wo . ')')
            ->orderBy('work_orders.id', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work as I don't have you database, but why not join the tables together and group the related records based on the count.

Something like.

```
$work_orders = DB::table('work_orders')
                ->select(
                   DB::raw('COUNT(work_order_tasks.work_order_id) count'),
                    'work_orders.*',
                    'vehicles.vin',
                    'work_orders.transportation_type as transport',
                    'clients.name as client_name',
                    'events.event_name as event_name'
                )
                ->havingRaw('count>0')
                ->groupBy('work_orders.id')
                ->where('status', '!=', 'Closed')
                ->where("work_order_tasks.status", "<>", "Completed")
                ->leftJoin('vehicles', 'vehicles.id', '=', 'work_orders.gsm_vehicle_id')
                ->leftJoin('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'work_orders.client_id')
                ->leftJoin('events', 'events.id', '=', 'work_orders.gsm_event_id')
                ->leftJoin('work_order_tasks', 'work_orders.id', '=','work_order_tasks.work_order_id')
                ->get();
```

Comment: This would return the opposite of what I am looking for.  I want to limit it to those records that have no status Pending records in work_order_tasks.